# iterate through all the selectedValues of ListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am programming a windows form application with c#. I have a listbox with ability of multiselect. how can I get the values of all the selected value?

```
  sql = " Select Division.* from Division ";
  DataTable divisionTable = client.GetDataTable(null, sql,  null);
  divisionListBox.DataSource = divisionTable;
  divisionListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
  divisionListBox.ValueMember = "BValue";                   
  divisionListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

I want to iterate through all the selected Values and get the total value of BValue of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SelectedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems?view=net-5.0) property, and it'll play nice with LINQ if you cast it to the [DataRowView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview.item?view=net-5.0) objects that an LB bound to a datatable contains. (The LB binds to datatable.DefaultView, which is a DataView, hence the DataRowView elements. DataRowViews have an Item indexer that accepts the column name):

```
var total = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>().Sum(drv => (int)drv["BValue"]);
```

If your datatable is strongly typed:

```
var total = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>().Sum(drv => (drv.Row as StronglyTypedRowName).BValue);
```

..which is nicer because it avoids string indexing, and means that if you rename BValue in code, it will update

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it
this is the answer

```
  int total = 0;
  foreach (System.Data.DataRowView item in divisionListBox.SelectedItems) 
  {
     total += item.Row.Field<int>(2) ;
  }
```

the (2) indicate the BValue in the sql sentence. the result of sql was like

Id, Name , Bvalue

so as I want to have BValue, I should use (2)

Comment: Always good to avoid "magic numbers" in code, and perhaps also positional indexing, if there's a risk the column order will change